# how can i clear this error in c# programing

Tags: c#

In this code every time `ShenasehSamapel` is two equal values I get an exception that says field `ShenasehSamapel` is not the primary key:

> "The variable name '@ShenasehSamapel' has already been declared.
>   Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure."

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
    private void btnDefineNewKala_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (txtShenasehSamapel.Text != "" & txtKalaName.Text != "")
        {
            //Anbar.FildArray[0]= txtRadif.Text;
            Anbar.FildArray [1]= txtShenasehSamapel.Text;
            Anbar.FildArray[2] =txtKalaName.Text;
            string strDefineKala = "insert into AnbarFava.dbo.DefineKala (ShenasehSamapel ,KalaName )" +
                                  " values ( @ShenasehSamapel , @KalaName )";
            //Anbar.AnbarCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Radif", Anbar.FildArray[0]);
            Anbar.AnbarCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShenasehSamapel", Anbar.FildArray[1]);
            Anbar.AnbarCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KalaName", Anbar.FildArray[2]);

            Anbar.RunQuery(strDefineKala);
            for (int Element = 0; Element <= Anbar.FildArray.Length - 1; Element++)
            {   Anbar.FildArray[Element] = null;    }
            //txtRadif.Text  = " ";
            txtShenasehSamapel.Text = "";
            txtKalaName.Text = "";
            /**/
            string strcmd = "select * from AnbarFava.dbo.DefineKala";
            SqlDataAdapter thisDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strcmd, Anbar.strCNN);
            DataTable thisDataTable = new DataTable();
            thisDataAdapter.Fill(thisDataTable);
            dgvDefineKala.DataSource = thisDataTable;
        }
        else
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("لطفا تمام خانه ها را پر کنید", "خطا",
                             MessageBoxButtons.OK); } 
    }
```

Comment: It *looks* like you're not clearing `Anbar.AnbarCMD.Parameters` between calls to `btnDefineNewKala_Click()`.

Comment: If you've downvoted this question, please take the time to explain why. Not everyone speaks native English and there isn't anything particularly wrong here.

Comment: @LukeP, [good luck with that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/164403).

Comment: Agree that there wasn't anything wrong except some pretty bad english. I went ahead and cleaned it up.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thank you. We as a community should be able to fix things like grammar and spelling. OP has clearly shown effort and has some code that they are struggling with.

Comment: @LukeP That's what the edit link is for :) No idea why 5 people thought this was downvote worthy.

Answer (score 5):

You are reusing connections and commands across function calls, you have a parameter from a previous call conflicting with your current call.

`Anbar.AnbarCMD` should not exist, you should create a new command each time. I also assume `Anbar` also holds a `SqlConnection` object, it should not be doing that either. All `Anbar` should hold is a connection string and a new connection and new command should be created each Click (Be sure to put the command and connection inside `using` statements so they get disposed)

I don't know exactly what `RunQuery` is doing but it could be rewritten to something similar to

```
public void RunQuery(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
    using(var command = new SqlQuery(query, connection)
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

You then call it like so

```
  var param1 = new SqlParameter("@ShenasehSamapel", Anbar.FildArray[1]);
  var param2 = new SqlParameter("@KalaName", Anbar.FildArray[2]);
  Anbar.RunQuery(strDefineKala, param1, param2);
```